# Rejected changes should not dismiss improvement requests

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

Documentation allows users to create "improvement requests" for topics and examples. Then, when other users submit a change set, they can indicate that their changes "handle" one or more of these "improvement requests". This part makes sense.

The problem is that if that change set is *rejected*, it seems that any and all improvement requests that it purported to handle are dismissed along with the rejected change set. This is a bug. Just because a change was rejected does not mean that the improvement request was invalid. And it has obviously not been handled, since the change was rejected.

An example of where this occurred can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/drafts/11605). I added an improvement request to generalize the example by not hard-coding file-system paths. Someone proposed changes that got off on a PowerShell tangent, which rene rightfully rejected. Although that did not address my improvement request, my request was still dismissed along with the rejected changes.<sup>*</sup>

**If a change set that handles an improvement request is rejected, the improvement request should not be marked as handled.**

If the improvement request is truly erroneous, it should have to be dismissed separately. This does not add a significant burden; it only takes a single user to "dismiss" an improvement request (which is a whole other issue, frankly, but one problem at a time).

---

<sup>*</sup> There is another curious bug lurking here as well. The change set draft is actually diff-ing against the [*current* version of the example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/15/compile-and-run-your-first-c-sharp-program/26/hello-world-using-net-framework#t=201607221246249795716), not the example as it stood when that change set was proposed. You can see this by [looking back in the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/revisions/15?exampleId=26). Juliano's changes were submitted 23 hours ago. [Carlos made changes](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/15531) 20 hours ago—more recently than Juliano—yet none of the stuff that appears "deleted" in that draft is actually there in Carlos's changes.
<sub>(Obviously, times are as of this writing, but the relative difference is what's important.)</sub>

Comment: I wonder if this bug is what I encountered yesterday when I saw nothing in two different diffs. Of course, I can't find them now, because I all I did was comment asking for clarification, and there's no record of comments... /me glares at screen

Comment: Hmm. That does sound like a bug. What's supposed to happen is that the requests are marked as handled when the proposed change is submitted and restored if it's rejected.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in the latest deploy.  If a change is retracted *or rejected* the improvement requests it purported to handle will be reopened.

Prior to this retraction was doing the right thing, but rejection was buggy.