# Documentation: Structuring and coordination

Tags: discussion, documentation

Today I created a topic "Loops" in the Bash tag (https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/drafts/35489).

After creating it I also noticed a topic "Control Structures" and within that topic there are lots of examples for if conditions and also loops. However, the "Syntax" and also "Parameters" sections only include information regarding tests. Thus, I think a topic for control structures in general are too broad and there is no real overview.

How to discuss these topic structures? I found no reasonable way in the documentation area to do that.

Comment: Consider: [A better documentation model: Task, not Topic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329183)