# Documentation made me look stupid

Tags: bug, edits, documentation

I submitted an edit for Documentation, and soon I was surprised to see that my edit was rejected. Then I looked at the reviewers arguments, and they were right -- but they talked not about my edit, but something completely different. Then I looked at the diff, and my edit did not contain my original changes, but something completely different, what was indeed a wrong thing, and the reviewers rightfully rejected it. I felt like stupid, that they believed I did the wrong thing, and it was also funny that my commit message was in disaccordance with the actual edit.

*What happened?*

- I fixed an obvious error, a typo in the code.
- Someone else (A) fixed the same typo.
- Some another person (B) improved a confusing text.
- The 2 other persons improvements were merged before mine.
- Consequently the diff of my edit did not show my improvement, as this part agreed with the most recent version, thanks to the edit from (A).
- But it shown that I changed the text fixed by (B) to the old, confusing version.

This method of merging parallel changes is very prone to errors, and results lots of frustration for editors. Hope it will be improved soon.

Comment: Actually, nobody look at your profile, but at your actions, probably none of the reviewers remember you, through that aside, can you share the links?

Comment: yes, myself I don't care too mch, I just wanted to highlight this mechanism, because this might cause problems. anyways, here is the edit, where the diff shows a change in a title, marking the old version as new, and the new version as old, and the commit message tells about the change I really made, which was only fixing a typo: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/40521?draftId=35497

Comment: There is a serious bug right now where Documentation changeset diffs actually diff against the *current* revision, not the revision against which you submitted your changes. Reported as an addendum [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328956/rejected-changes-should-not-dismiss-improvement-requests). This is probably why you were confused when you went back and looked at your submission later.

Comment: Missing a way to go and see the edit history from that proposed change view too

Comment: IMO, this is actually a fundamental problem with the entire concept of doing edit reviews on documentation.  With Wikipedia, having millions of people editing the content works, because changes are instant.  In the worst case, rollbacks are uglier, but it avoids these sorts of synchronization issues.  I can't imagine how this can possibly succeed long-term with the requirement that edits be approved.  That model barely even works for code, when the creators have the ability to manually fix merge conflicts using vi, much less in a web interface that's trying to hide that complexity....