# Proposed change doesn't show any changes in diff view

Tags: bug, documentation

When reviewing a change in a [PowerShell topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/44065) I don't see any any changes in the diff using any of the views:

[image: no changes in diff]

It will only allow comments for the "run commands" example so I assume that was the section changed, but with no visible edits I don't know what the change was.

Comment: Possibly the same as the one mentioned in [Rejected changes should not dismiss improvement requests](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328956)

Comment: Ah.. thanks for the link! I tried searching but didn't find anything.

Comment: Sure thing. I'm just trying to link related material.  It's not a dupe by any means, since the problem is just mentioned as a footnote there.

Comment: Yep... And it looks like the original edit was approved http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/powershell/revisions/3087?exampleId=11031 so this edit is either a duplicate or wasn't closed correctly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/67005 not invalidated by http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/67296 .

Comment: This also happened to me [in this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/115113?filter-tags=java). I tried to reject with custom reason twice, but I kept getting an error. Finally I clicked 'Approve' and it accepted my review.