# Seemingly blank edit on Docs

Tags: bug, documentation

This edit on the Documentation Beta has no visible changes at all:

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/64827

I tried to reproduce the same situation and found I was able to submit an example where the only change is a single extra newline, which is not easily visible when looking at the proposed change:

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/65876

Can we please update the software to deal with this better? Either block pure whitespace only edits (as the Q&A site does) or make them visible in the diff? Or even better, do both of these things.

Due to the length of a documentation page, it is time consuming to scroll through and try to figure out what has changed.

Comment: Probably the same: [Proposed change doesn't show any changes in diff view](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329578)